# Semantic segmentation results is all black all bits are the same no mask

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

When I use the code below to perform Semantic semgentation on my owndataset(40 images) and annotations(1 class(myface) and the annotations in cocojson format) I got just black image no mask and all bits are the same and the model accuracy in all epochs is 67.87% but loss is going down in each epoch :

```
import cv2
import os
import json
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from sklearn.utils import compute_sample_weight
folder_path = "D:\\ImageClassification\\face_semantic_segmentation\\dataset"
filenames = os.listdir(folder_path)
images = []
for filename in filenames:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder_path, filename))
    img = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
    img = np.array(img)
    images.append(img)
x_train = np.array(images)
with open("D:\\ImageClassification\\face_semantic_segmentation\\annotations.json") as f:
    coco = json.load(f)
annotations = coco['annotations']
masks = {}
for annotation in annotations:
    image_id = annotation['image_id']
    if image_id not in masks:
        masks[image_id] = []
    masks[image_id].append(annotation['segmentation'])
resized_masks = []
for image_id, mask in masks.items():
    mask_img = np.zeros((720, 1280), dtype=np.uint8)
    for segmentation in mask:
        poly = np.array(segmentation).reshape((-1, 1, 2)).astype(np.int32)
        cv2.fillPoly(mask_img, [poly], 1)
    mask_img = cv2.resize(mask_img, (256, 256))
    mask_img = np.stack([mask_img] * 3, axis=-1)
    resized_masks.append(mask_img)
y_train = np.array(resized_masks)
y_train.shape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
mask = y_train[4]
mask = np.sum(mask, axis=-1)
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()
from segmentation_models import Unet
from segmentation_models import get_preprocessing
from segmentation_models.losses import bce_jaccard_loss
from segmentation_models.metrics import iou_score
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

BACKBONE = 'resnet50'
preprocess_input = get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)

model = Unet(BACKBONE,classes=2,input_shape=(256,256, 3), encoder_weights='imagenet',activation='sigmoid')
x_train = preprocess_input(x_train)
x = model.layers[-1].output
x = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,batch_size=32,epochs=50)
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried training the model with Dice loss? also when you have 2 classes, use 1 neuron with sigmoid and binary_CE loss or 2 softmax with categorical_CE loss.

Comment: no I didn't try Dice loss do I need to since I have just 2 classes